# "tax_query" parameter is ignored when "p" parameter is set in WP_Query

Tags: wp-query

I have a query object, where both `tax_query` and `p` parameters are set

```
[query] => Array
    (
        [tax_query] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [taxonomy] => destination_tag
                        [field] => slug
                        [terms] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => country
                            )

                    )

            )

        [post_type] => dc-location
        [lang] => en
        [posts_per_page] => 10
        [paged] => 1
        [p] => 7
    )
```

The resulting SQL query ignores the tax_query parameter

```
[request] => SELECT   wptests_posts.* FROM wptests_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wptests_posts.ID = 7 AND wptests_posts.post_type = 'dc-location'  ORDER BY wptests_posts.post_date DESC
```

If I remove the `p` parameter, the query includes the tax query correctly. Is there a way to force the sql to parse `tax_query` even if `p` is defined?

Comment: Have you tried `post__in` instead of `p`? Why are you trying to combine them anyway? What's your goal?

Comment: @swissspidy the goal is to return a post only if it has a taxonomy term. It's an API design constraint. `post_in` works as expected, put the comment as an answer and I will accept it, I will open a track ticket on WP to understand if this is the desired behavior, it should at least be documented

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`p` is a special argument in `WP_Query` in that it short-circuits most of the query parsing logic to request a single post.

In your case, I'd suggest using the `post__in` argument when you need to use `tax_query` at the same time.